# Añadir archivos externos a repositorio

Tags: git

Verán, lo que quiero, es, poder añadir archivos externos a la carpeta de mi repositorio.

Para que sea más entendible, vean:

Tengo un repositorio en la carpeta `/foo/bar/`. Sin embargo, me gustaría poder "rastrear" los cambios de un archivo `/eggs/oof/codigo.c` (por decir algo), es decir, hacer que mi archivo `/eggs/oof/codigo.c` sea parte del repositorio sin estar en la carpeta del mismo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con los detalle que has dado la respuesta sería que no.

Git funciona con una carpeta `.git` en el repositorio raíz y lleva inventario de todo lo que hay en esa carpeta. Así que la máxima es que todo debería estar bajo esa raíz.

Dicho eso hay "apaños". Uno de ellos es mover los ficheros al repo y hacer un symlink a otros sitios donde los necesites.

Otro sería usar git submodules, en caso de que esos ficheros ya estuviesen en otro repositorio de código

Un tercero, suponiendo que son ficheros de código sería crear librerías e importarlas donde necesites.. nada relacionado con git.

Y por último, si, worktree podría ser una solución y no, worktree no es la solución para tu problema.
La idea de los working tree es tener varias ramas en diferentes paths al mismo tiempo. Tiene mucho sentido para gente que trabaja con repositorios muy grandes o que tienen requisitos especiales (como pasar tests sobre varias versiones de código a la vez) no está pensado para este caso de uso en concreto.

Answer (score 1):

Lo más recomendable en este caso es mover el archivo `/eggs/oof/codigo.c` a la carpeta de tu repositorio `/foo/bar` para poder trackear los cambios al mismo y luego crear un [link simbólico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enlace_simb%C3%B3lico) en su directorio original:

1. Mueve el archivo relevante:

   ```
   $ mv /eggs/oof/codigo.c /foo/bar
   ```
2. Dentro de tu repositorio crea un link simbólico de la nueva ubicación, hacia la carpeta donde el archivo exístia:

   ```
   $bar ln -s codigo.c ../eggs/oof
   ```
3. Agrega el nuevo archivo para poder "rastrear" los cambios:

   ```
   $bar git add codigo.c
   ```

Referencia: [git: How do you add an external directory to the repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383754/git-how-do-you-add-an-external-directory-to-the-repository)